# WP 7.1 Listpicker: Selected value display object name instead of property

Tags: binding, windows-phone-7.1, listpicker

I got a problem with my ListPicker for WP 7.1, my selected value doesn´t display the binding instead it display the object name for the model I have as ItemSource. However when i goes to FullModeItemTemplate my bindings is working just fine. I have checked my output and haven´t got any bindings errors..

Here is my code.

```
public class TurnoverModel
{
    public string TurnoverId { get; set; }
    public string TurnoverDesc { get; set; }
}
```

my model iam passing in as a collection to ItemSource

```
         <toolkit:ListPicker ItemsSource="{Binding TurnoverList}" Width="350" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="turnOverListPicker" SelectionMode="Multiple"}" Header="Turnover" SelectionChanged="OnTurnoverChanged">
            <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TurnoverDesc}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
            <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TurnoverDesc}" Width="150"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
        </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

If someone have any ideas why my bindings isn´t working i will appreciate all answeres,
thx

Answer (score 0):

```
 <toolkit:ListPicker ItemsSource="{Binding TurnoverList}" Width="350" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="turnOverListPicker" SelectionMode="Multiple"}" Header="Turnover" SelectionChanged="OnTurnoverChanged"> 
<toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
 <DataTemplate> 
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"> 
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TurnoverDesc}" Width="150"/>
 </StackPanel>
 </DataTemplate>
 </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
 </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

on selectionchanged event write :

```
 private void OnTurnoverChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
     TurnoverModel selecteditem = e.AddedItems[0] as TurnoverModel;
     String turnoverId =selecteditem.TurnoverId;
     String turnoverDesc =selecteditem.TurnoverDesc; 
    }
========================================================================
```

Comment: Maybe You could elaborate a bit more on this?